# regex to find consecutive digits in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find multiple consecutive digits through regex in javascript

Let's say I've got:

```
12345abc123
```

I want to know how many times I've got 3 or more consecutive digits. Right now I'm using:

```
/\d{3}/g
```

But that gives me: 123, 123 and I want to have: 123, 234, 345, 123

How can I change my regex to get want I want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/(?=(\d{3}))/g
```

#### [Online Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/iE2xM4/2)

**Code:**

```
var re = /(?=(\d{3}))/g; 
var str = '12345abc789';
var m;
while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    console.log(m[1]);
}
```

**Output:**

```
123
234
345
789
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, I was trying it with grouping but did not hit the good one

Comment: @anubhava Why you added `.` at the last?

Comment: the `.` at the end of your regular expression should be removed

Comment: It will work without it since grouping is inside the lookahead. (updated the regex)

Answer (score 4):

You'd have to use look-ahead assertions:

```
var str = '12345abc123', 
re = /\d(?=(\d\d))/g;

while ((match = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // each match is an array comprising
    // - the first digit and
    // - the next two digits
    console.log(match.join(''));
}
```

It matches a digit if followed by another two; the assertion causes the engine to start the next search right after the first matched digit.

Answer (score 1):

This is the regex you are looking for:

```
/(?=(\d{3}))/g
```