# How can i extract a number in a paragraph, which is stuck between two <b>-Tags with node.js and cheerio?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

Im trying to get the number 18,267 in the following html code:

```
<div class="mod mod-text" id="-1199962081">   

<article class="clearfix">  

<h2>Current situation in Switzerland<br></h2>

<h3>2.4.2020, 8 am, cases confirmed in Switzerland:</h3>

<p><b>No. of people tested positive (for coronavirus):</b>18,267
<b><br>Deaths:</b> 432 people</p>
<p>blabla</p>
</article>
</div>
```

For this i tried to use the following code:

```
axios.get(url).then((res) => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
        $('#-1934206868').children().children('p').each((index,element) => {
            const text = $(element).text();
            textElements[index] = {text};
        });
        console.log(textElements[2]);
    });
```

But if i try it like this i get the following output

```
{
  text: 'No. of people tested positive (for coronavirus): 18 267\n' +
    ' Deaths: 432 people'
}
```

Which brings me to my question: How can I just get number from this paragraph, instead of the whole block with both  tags? Or alternatively: How can i then parse the object i get from my code into a string which a can split to extract the number?

Comment: This could be solved using Regex. Check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24904573/8657006

Answer (score 0):

Although your code is html, not xml, something like should work:

```
var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString('[your code above]' ,'text/xml');
var xpath = require('xpath');
var nodes = xpath.select("//p/text()", doc)

console.log(nodes[0].toString())
```

Output:

```
18,267
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't select text nodes with cheerio so you have to use pure js at some point:

```
$('b')[0].nextSibling.data
```